# SUMIF with several OR criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

[image]

The blue cell summates to 1, but that is not correct and it should summate to more because of the row text match with B47 row. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: your question is a very valuable one, and it might be interesting also for others. However it's title is not describing it's content, please change it to a more relevant one (e.g. SUMIF with several OR criteria).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SUMIF` is not supposed to work with more than one criteria (you can't check multiple criteria within one SUMIF as you tried in your formula).
This formula will calculate the right result for you: `=SUM(B3:BI3*(IFERROR(MATCH(B2:BI3,B47:AL47,0)>0,0)))`, this is an array formula, so you need to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after it.

- `MATCH(...)`: look for all students whether they are in the list with requirments (this is the part which works only as array formula)
- `IFERROR(...)`: converts `#N/A` errors to `0`

Comment: Juhasz Thank you for answering this question. I ended up manually doing it before I got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you are trying to calculate the number of students for a particular project with skill1 and skill2.

You may also try using COUNTIFS() function. This works for multiple criteria.